# play framework slow at first call

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an issue, with playframework just after startup.

I have this simple controller:

```
@Singleton
class BomberManController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok("test")
  }
}
```

On first call, on prod env, the request take 400ms, at the second request it take 2ms.

I don't understand why and how optimise that. On my project the request must take less than 300ms.

Did you have any idea?

PlayVersion: 2.6

Comment: If you are saying that the JVM takes a long to start and run your very first request, that is to be expected. The JVM interpreter will "warm up" when code is called more than once and will proceed to compile it into native code, which runs  substantially faster.

Comment: Thanks, but I have not this behaviours with spring. And it's not verry good behaviours for microservice design...
There are no way to optimize that?

Comment: You can "warm up" the service by sending it some simple requests when it starts.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a dummy `Request` and apply it directly in the constructor of the controller via `index.apply(request)`. Consider the definition and the call point of `warmUp` method bellow:

```
@Singleton 
class BomberManController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  warmUp()

  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok("test")   
  }

  private def warmUp() = {
    val requestFactory = new DefaultRequestFactory(HttpConfiguration())
    val request =
      requestFactory.createRequest(
        RemoteConnection("127.0.0.1", false, None),
        "GET",
        RequestTarget("/", "/", Map.empty),
        "HTTP/1.1",
        Headers(),
        TypedMap.empty,
        AnyContentAsEmpty
      )
    index.apply(request)   
  } 
}
```

In production `BomberManController` is instantiated on application start and thus `warmUp` will be called which in turn hits `index` endpoint.

To test this production behaviour locally, set [`play.http.secret.key`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ApplicationSecret#Generating-an-application-secret) in `application.conf` and start application with

```
 sbt clean runProd
```

If you do not wish to pollute your controllers with `warmUp` utility methods, you could separate this concern into an utility singleton, say `WarmUpUtility`, and make use of [eager singleton binding](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings). For example:

```
@Singleton 
class WarmUpUtility @Inject()(bomberManController: BomberManController)() {

  warmUp()

  private def warmUp() = {
    val requestFactory = new DefaultRequestFactory(HttpConfiguration())
    val request =
      requestFactory.createRequest(
        RemoteConnection("127.0.0.1", false, None),
        "GET",
        RequestTarget("/", "/", Map.empty),
        "HTTP/1.1",
        Headers(),
        TypedMap.empty,
        AnyContentAsEmpty
      )
    bomberManController.index.apply(request)
  }

}

// Module should be in the root package 
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[WarmUpUtility]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have do that, but it's not a beautiful solution :s